# How to access a known Ember component from console

Tags: javascript, ember.js, google-chrome-devtools

Using Ember debug Chrome extension, I have identified this component in a website I am trying to automate (but do not have direct access to change the code):

```
<MYAPP@component:zipcode-field::ember592>
```

Which is shown in hierarchy as:

```
application
    engine
        myui
            zipcodeField
```

If I edit the `value` property of that element in the debugger, it updates the UI and model as desired. Can I do this via a one-liner from the console?

Update: So far, I am able to enter this in the console:

```
Ember.lookup.$E.container.lookup("MYAPP@component:zipcode-field")
```

But unable to access/alter its `value` property as in the debugger.

**Update:**

In feedback to one of the answers, my aim is to have a console one-liner, which could be given to someone without any debuggers installed in order to run the code with the same behaviour. Using a variable such as `$E` within the console requires that the element has been manually selected prior to running the code, which would not be sufficient.

Comment: Can you link to the site in question? Also, if updating the value property worked then I assume you could just update the value with pure javascript (outside of Ember) and then if necessary just trigger whatever event Ember is expecting (if any)?

Comment: I cannot link to this specific site for privacy reasons, sorry. I'd be happy to update it via pure JS, but have been as yet unable to do so. `Ember.lookup.$E.container.lookup("MYAPP@component:zipcode-field")` in console does not allow editing the `value` property / doesn't update the UI or model.

Comment: What's the point of the ember code in your comment? Why not just use `document.querySelector` to set the value? Like `document.querySelector('input[placeholder="zip code goes here"]').value = '94109';`

Comment: The ember code from comment when entered in console does seem to select the right element, but without being able to set it / update the Ember model (sorry, it may actually update the UI, just not the rest of the model which usually updates from manually inputting into the field). It has no unique identifiers to target via css/xpath, only ember generated ids...

Comment: Well, this worked in the dev tools on Ember's frontpage's first example (page already has jQuery, and if you're using an extension you can inject it if it's not there). `jQuery('input[placeholder="Enter your name"]').val("blah").trigger("change")`. Hope that helps. Honestly, I don't think there's enough info provided here to truly answer this question... "It has no unique identifiers to target via css/xpath, only ember generated ids..." is hard for me to believe.

Comment: I'll try to recreate the effect in a page / find another example which is public. With Ember, ExtJS, etc, it is not uncommon to have things which are don't have unique IDs to target with css/xpath. As the IDs/classes can be generated dynamically, each page load can be different if number of elements changes by 1.

Comment: Gotcha, let me know if you find a public example. You may be right that you can't programmatically identify the correct element without Ember, but in my experience there's always *something* to base it off of... "Oh it's always next to static text with this class or it's always the 4th element after an ad."

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve here? And by debugger do you mean the ember inspector?

Answer (score 19):

Correct me if I am wrong but it seems that you aren't using the [ember inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en) (available on [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/ember-inspector/) and as a [bookmarklet](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector#bookmarklet-all-browsers)).

Once you have that installed it is really easy to inspect debug and modify anything ember related, for the purpose of this answer I will be using the chrome version.

Open up your chrome dev tools in the tab that has your ember app running,
once there head to the ember tab in the developer tools.

In order to see the components you will have to tick a checkbox

[image: enable components]

Once enabled you will be able to see all of the components currently used.

Clicking on a component will open up a panel that contains all of the component's properties.

[image: property panel]

In order to access those properties from the console all you need to do is click on the `$E` next to the components.

Once clicked you should see something similar in the console.

```
Ember Inspector ($E):  Class {helperName: (...), logout: (...), isOpenBinding: StreamBinding, currentUserBinding: StreamBinding, _morph: Morph…}
```

Now all you need to do in order to get the property values:

```
$E.get('myProperty');
```

And To set them:

```
$E.set('myProperty', newValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for this really detailed answer. Please see my update in the original question as to why the `$E` would not be helpful in this situation.

Comment: The first line states "Using Ember debug Chrome extension" - is that different to the Ember Inspector?

Comment: @leon if you use something like jQurry to find the object and pull out its ID attribute you can then use the method in my answer.

Comment: ahh my bad, well you could always set a unique id to the component via the [elementId](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_elementId) property. Then again you said you can't touch the code :/

Comment: Can't seem to understand why someone would need to modify component values via the console and not through the ember inspector

Answer (score 15):

A component is just a view, so the following should work:

`Ember.View.views[<GUID>]`

So in your example:

`Ember.View.views['ember592']`

You need to use get/set if you want to modify/read the `value` property, for example:

`Ember.View.views['ember592'].get('value')`

`Ember.View.views['ember592'].set('value', 'newValue')`

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I'm after. I haven't tried this on the target site yet, but won't the `ember592` change easily based on how many ember elements are added to the DOM? Is it possible to use your method, but targeting the `zipcodeField` element?

Comment: Yep.. You can use something like jQuery to find the particular div (based on things like class names etc), then pull the divs ID attribute and that is the GUID 'emberXXXX'

Comment: Use the elements tab of the inspector and try find what's different about the zipcodeField to work out what to search with.. If you want a hand writing the jQuery (or raw JavaScript is jQuery isn't on the page) paste the <div> open and close tags in the comments here

Comment: As per comments in original question - assume that there are no usable ID's/classes as it's all ember generated and I don't have control over the code. So - I can use the debug tool to locate and modify properties, but I need a console one-liner which I envision uses Ember to locate the Ember-produced element. If Angular, I would assume to do something like `App.controller('controllerName').modelName = newValue; App.controller('controllerName').applyOrRefresh` or such. I've used something like this to force refresh the UI from model, which would otherwise only update when UI is interacted with

Comment: You could loop through all views. For example, this loops through all views and prints the toString() value:

Comment: var key, view;
for (key in Ember.View.views) {
    view = Ember.View.views[key];
    console.log(view.toString());
}

Comment: This should work: var key, view; for (key in Ember.View.views) { view = Ember.View.views[key]; if (view.toString().indexOf('<MYAPP@component:zipcode-field::') === 0) { console.log('do stuff'); } }

Comment: Additionally - Ember apps also have a container you can use to lookup objects.. The way it works is: if the object type is singleton - return the singleton.. if the object type is not singleton - create instance and return instance.. Views are not singletons so this wouldn't have helped. Controllers are singletons.. If the zipcodeField value is attached to a controller you could access that controller like: GlobalAppVariable.__container__.lookup('controller:controller-name')

Comment: Also would like to know, @jmurphyau

Answer (score 3):

Found a gist that works with Ember 2.13

```
App.__container__.lookup('-view-registry:main')[componentId]; // componentId i.e. "ember4322"
```

Credit goes to ngyv: https://gist.github.com/ngyv/819e2cc78eca2a3b19599707e1461205