# How to toggle Ember feature flags from the devtools console

Tags: ember.js

I'm using the [ember-feature-flags](https://github.com/kategengler/ember-feature-flags) addon to provide some way to toggle new UI features in my ember application.

The docs say that you can toggle these features at runtime:

```
this.get('features').enable('newHomepage');
this.get('features').disable('newHomepage');
```

However, this does not work at "runtime" in the devtools console because the `this` context will refer to the Window object. I do NOT want to rely on the Ember Inspector and the answer to [this existing question] does not work for me: [How to access a known Ember component from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759015/how-to-access-a-known-ember-component-from-console) (either because the Ember version I'm on does not expose that information or this is a features service, not a component).

I want to be able to do this in native JavaScript, running in the devtools, that can be ported to a simple bookmarklet to give to other folks to toggle the feature flag on and off on their machines.

Ultimately, I think I'm trying to get the Ember application's instance in order to do something similar to what is possible with the Inspector, but instead of doing `$E.get('features')...`, I would need to do `EmberAppInstance.get('features')...`. I don't know how to get that app instance, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some digging, I found a solution I'm happy with using the following in Ember 2.13:

`Ember.Application.NAMESPACES_BY_ID['app-name'].__container__.lookup('controller:application').get('features').enable('newHomePage');`

I'm able to use the app's name (replace "app-name" with your app's name) to find it in the namespace array and then look up the application controller, where the features service is injected. From there, all the ember-feature-flags methods are available for viewing/toggling feature flags. A bit cumbersome, but does the trick without any new addons/dependencies, or the Ember Inspector.

Answer (score 1):

By default this is done with [ember-export-application-global](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-export-application-global). Basically it exposes your app under a global called as your app is called.

However *by default not on production builds*! However you can configure this by setting `exportApplicationGlobal: true` in your environment configuration.

Comment: I'd prefer to not include any new addons or dependencies. It seems reasonable to assume that if the Ember Inspector can do this in an app that doesn't include that addon, then there must be some way to get a reference to it without exposing a global. I was able to solve this with some hard-coded references: `Ember.Application.NAMESPACES[2].__container__.lookup('controller:application').get('features').isEnabled('newHomePage');`. I'm going to keep tinkering around before I suggest this answer.

Comment: You probably already have that add-on. It's by default installed.